# Python documenting default parameter values

Tags: python, doxygen

We run Doxygen on our Python code to generate documentation. Some functions contain parameters that are optional, as they have default values. The fact that they are optional and their default values are currently undocumented. Is there a correct way to document this information so Doxygen will read it?

As an example, here is a simple method. x is optional and has the default value 0. How could I document this with Doxygen?

`## Prints a number.
 #  @param self The object pointer.
 #  @param x A number to print.
 def printNum(self, x = 0):`

Comment: Which version version of doxygen are you using? What would you like to see x as documentation?

Comment: Version 1.8.8 it looks like. I don't know exactly what I would like to see. I would like to know if there is some system to tag the parameter as optional, besides just typing it in English in the @param parameter description.

Comment: PLease have a look at the current version (1.8.13)